# Can't bind DataContext in element ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

In my UserConterl.

```
<UserControl.Resources >
    <ResourceDictionary >       
        <ContextMenu x:Key="MyContextMenu " >
            <MenuItem Header="{Binding Header}">
        </ContextMenu >
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate  x:Key="MyTemplate">
        <TextBlock x:Key="MyTextBlock" Text = {Binding Header} ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyContextMenu }"/>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate >
     </ResourceDictionary > 
</UserControl.Resources>

 <TreeView  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding MySources}" >
```

above codes in xaml.There codes is in .cs of UserControl xaml.

```
    public MyUserControl()
    {           
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
    }


    public class MyViewModel: ViewModelBase
    {
       public string Header {get; set;}
       public List<string> MySources \\ Has been assigned
    }
```

The result expected is that display the field **Header** when I click rightbutton.Actually, the Popup Menu is empty.I found ContextMenu didn't bind DataContext. What should I do?
 Thank!

Comment: If you are running in debug mode, can you check output window for any binding errors.

Comment: Just checking the blindingly obvious: is this a copy/paste of the code you're trying to run? You seem to have linked your UserControl to something called MyViewModel, when your Header property is in DataSheetManagerViewModel.

Comment: @Pravin no.. I don't know if DataContext in ResourceDictionary will inherit UserControl.

Comment: @goobering yep,you're right. I have fixed it.

Comment: Excellent. If you're satisfied that you've found an answer, could you possibly mark it as 'accepted' to keep the question out of the Unanswered pool?

Comment: @goobering - -ll ... I mean I just fix my word wrong.......

Comment: No worries - I take it your DataContext still isn't binding?

Comment: @goobering That's right.Look the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minus setting up your datacontext, if you are trying to bind context menu items to a parent control's datacontext, you have to use the PlacementTarget.Tag trick. This is because the context menu is on a different visual tree.

You also don't need the Header in `<TextBlock  Text="{Binding Header}"`, leave it as `<TextBlock  Text="{Binding}"`

```
<Grid Background="DarkGray">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="CM">
            <MenuItem Header="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.Header,
                                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu, Mode=FindAncestor}}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate  x:Key="MyTemplate">
            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding}"  
                        ContextMenu="{StaticResource CM }" 
                        Tag="{Binding DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeView, Mode=FindAncestor}}"/>
  </HierarchicalDataTemplate >
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TreeView Grid.Row="0" 
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Sources}"></TreeView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I never used PlacementTarget.It's right after using PlacementTarget. The Answer is your.